# python: retrieving ceiling key and floor key in a dictionary or a set

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

I have a dictionary with a bunch of integer keys. for keys I don't have, I'd like to be able to retrieve the smallest and largest keys right before and after they key I want to retrieve but that does not exist.
The Treemap class in java has two methods doing exactly this: `ceilingkey()` and `floorkey()`.

> How can I do this with python?

As an example I have a dictionary like this:

```
 { 1: "1", 4: "4", 6: "6" ..., 100: "100" }
```

If I ask for key `1`, I'll retrieve `"1"`, 
but if I look for key `3`, I should get `KeyError` and hence be able to get `floor(3) = 1` and `ceil(3) = 4`.

Comment: Could you give us an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```python
def floor_key(d, key):
    if key in d:
        return key
    return max(k for k in d if k < key)

def ceil_key(d, key):
    if key in d:
        return key
    return min(k for k in d if k > key)
```

I'm not sure how you want to handle border conditions. Note that this will raise an exception (`ValueError`) if you are asking for the floor/ceiling of a key that's lower/higher than anything in the dict.

Comment: this looks like the correct approach. I'm guessing if the algorithm can be optimized by making use of a binary search.

Comment: @marcorossi: that's true. I just changed it to use min() and max() instead of sorting it. I think that is more efficient, eh?

Comment: No need to build the list. Just take the brackets out to use a generator expression.

Comment: If you add a try and a except to return None, you could handle the error case. I think this is the best approach, simple and fast.

Comment: @Jblasco `O(N)` for each missing key lookup, not so fast.

Comment: @nofinator You can iterate over the dict itself, `d.keys()` is useless.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module here, in case the key the not found then it can find the ceil and floor values in `O(log N)` time.:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> from random import randint
def get_value(dic, key):
    if key in dic:
        return dic[key]
    else:
        ind = bisect.bisect(keys, key)
        d = {}
        if ind > 0:
            d["floor"] = dic[keys[ind-1]]
        if ind < len(keys):
            d["ceil"] = dic[keys[ind]]
        return d
...     
>>> dic = {randint(0,100) : x  for x in xrange(10)}
>>> dic
{65: 6, 4: 5, 1: 7, 40: 8, 10: 4, 50: 0, 68: 2, 27: 9, 61: 3}
```

Create a sorted list of keys for `bisect`:

```
>>> keys = sorted(dic)
>>> keys
[1, 4, 10, 27, 40, 50, 61, 65, 68]
```

Now use the function:

```
>>> get_value(dic, 4)
5
```

For `3` both ceil and floor are avaiable:

```
>>> get_value(dic, 3)
{'ceil': 5, 'floor': 7}
```

`0` is smaller than the smallest key, so this will return only `ceil`:

```
>>> get_value(dic, 0)
{'ceil': 7}
```

For keys greater than the largest key only `floor` value will be returned:

```
>>> get_value(dic, 70)
{'floor': 2}
```

Comment: this is close, but i want a floorkey() and ceilingkey(), hence returning the smallest closest KEY and the smallest largest KEY for my key. If i returns a tuple with also the associated value it's a plus. Also, keys is undefined.

Comment: @marcorossi what should `floorkey` return for a key that is smaller than the smallest key?

Comment: @marcorossi what do you mean by `keys is undefined`?

Comment: That you're using variable keys in bisect.bisect(), but keys is undefined.

Comment: @marcorossi I've defined `keys` below it, it is `keys = sorted(dic)`. Posted the function above it to make it more readable.

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, adding a new element to the dictionary will require the sorted keys to be rebuilt, hence while the retrieval itself is `O(log N)`, but modification is `O(N log N)`. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fun one using bisect.

```
import bisect

def ceiling_key(d, key):
    keys = sorted(d.keys())
    idx = bisect.bisect_left(keys, key)
    if key in d:
        idx += 1
    return keys[idx]

def floor_key(d, key):
    keys = sorted(d.keys())
    idx = bisect.bisect_left(keys, key) - 1
    return keys[idx]


...

>>> ceiling_key(d, 1)
4
>>> ceiling_key(d, 2)
4
>>> ceiling_key(d, 4)
6
>>> ceiling_key(d, 3)
4
>>> ceiling_key(d, 2)
4
>>> ceiling_key(d, 1)
4
>>> ceiling_key(d, 0)
1
>>> ceiling_key(d, 6)
100
>>> floor_key(d, 6)
4
>>> floor_key(d, 7)
6
>>> floor_key(d, 101)
100
>>> floor_key(d, 100)
6
```

Comment: this is cool. i think there's a bug in ceiling_key. The result of bisect_left should not have +1.

Comment: Ah good catch. I pasted that code before I tested it, and I forgot to update my answer after I changed it. Thanks.

Comment: What's the point of using `bisect` here, if you're going to call `sorted` each time you call these functions. So, this is still `O(NlogN)` for accessing any key.

Comment: That's true. The sorting could happen outside of the function call.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `bisect_right` in the `floor_key`?

Comment: I think you should also consider situation when `idx==-1` (e.g. raise `ValueError`) because now it will return last key and that's not what you want I guess.

Comment: @nme Yeah true. I just tested it out and you do get the last key with the floor_key function which probably isn't expected behavior.